# Can't see my page when using XAMPP

Tags: xampp, ubuntu-12.04, document-root

Today I started working with XAMPP for Ubuntu 12.04. I changed the configuration of the Apache Server for the document root from /opt/lamp/htdcos to the project location of Aptana Studio 3 (/var/www), after that i started XAMPP and tried to access to my Page, which is the file index.html in the folder Homepage (I wrote 
    http:// localhost/Homepage/index.html
),but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try `http:// localhost/Homepage`

Comment: I think you mapped the path incorrectly then...check if your path is correct...!!

Comment: I already checked that. The path is correct, because when I try http:// localhost XAMPP is showing me the default index.html in the right way. Maybe this problem has to do with permissions?

Comment: Is there maybe another more comfortable way to bring my projects from the Aptana Studio directory to the document root?

Comment: If you have mapped the route correctly, then localhost should lead you to the directory you have pointed it to and not the default index page...

Comment: Problem solved, it was because I forgot to change the directory, I only changed document root